# How to remove brackets (chevrons) in php

Tags: php, str-replace, brackets

out there, I have a question:

I want to remove chevrons (brackets) from a string in `php`:

Example: `string= ">Autor</"` I want to remove the `<` and `</`, but how to do this?

I tried this:

```
$result = ">Autor</";
$result = str_replace(arr0ay(">","</"),"",$result);
echo $result;
```

But it won't remove the characters I want to be removed, does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
//list contains attributes, like Autor, Titel

```
foreach($list as $show){ 
$show = trim($show); 
$text=htmlspecialchars($xml->hits->hit[$j]->info); 
echo $show." = "; 
preg_match ("/$show.*$show/", $text, $result); 
$result = implode($result); 
$result = str_replace(array("$show",">","</"),"",$result); 
$result = str_replace(array(">","</"),"",$result); 
echo $result;
}
```

Comment: [Its working fine for me](https://eval.in/410958)

Comment: I've try u're code it work for me, can you paste all you're code ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually if i use just ur code, its working, but in my total php file it doesnt work. I want to read out of an xml file, and want to remove the brackets arround the diffrent attributes:   //list are the attributes, like Autor, Titel
 foreach($list as $show){
  $show = trim($show);
  $text=htmlspecialchars($xml->hits->hit[$j]->info);
  echo $show." = ";
  preg_match ("/$show.*$show/", $text, $result); 
  $result = implode($result);
  $result = str_replace(array("$show",">","</"),"",$result);
  $result = str_replace(array(">","</"),"",$result);
  echo $result;

Comment: you should put updates like these in your question, its almost impossible to read them in comment form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out, how to do it, and if someone else have the same problem is i got, he will know how to do it:

You need to do it with str_replace("oldstring_to_find", "newstring_oldstring_get_replaced_with","variable");

Thx for your help